# Separate web app as 'V' in rails app?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, polymer-1.0

I am developing a RoR app. I am confused whether to develop an API in rails app and separate web app using different javascript frameworks. 
Reasons: Am a beginner in ruby on rails. Unable to customize views using frameworks like Polymer. (Found few gems, but I feel like its easy with normal web app).

So I need your suggestion in deciding whether to develop api with rails and interact with it using a separate web app(HTML5 and JS) or complete project in rails (if so then please suggest me some useful gems in designing beautiful views)
PS. I also want to develop API because mobile apps gonna interact with it.

Comment: This is mostly an opinion, but IMO I'd do things completely separately.

Comment: Can you be specific by doing "completely separately"? I mean how you implemented FE and BE?

Comment: I mean I'd develop any FE apps outside of the Rails app if Rails is serving as the API server. I'd also probably consider using one of the Rails API gems since there's a lot going on in Rails that isn't that useful for an API-only app.

Comment: If seperate FE and BE then do I need to host two apps seperately or is there any way to host in a common place.

Answer (score 2):

If you're gonna do mobile applications, use rails to build an API.

It's easy to render json with rails, so it's powerful to build an API that you'll be able to use in web with JS framework (like angularjs) and for mobiles applications.

See here for how to render json : http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html

Hope it help

Comment: Thank you. Can you help by adding some good example or tutorial to build API with rails app (for beginners would be helpful)?

Comment: If you're new to rails, you should enroll the free Rails for zombies tutorial by codeschool : https://www.codeschool.com/courses/rails-for-zombies-redux


And for API see : https://www.amberbit.com/blog/2014/2/19/building-and-documenting-api-in-rails/ and https://www.codeschool.com/blog/2014/02/03/token-based-authentication-rails/ and also http://andrewberls.com/blog/post/api-versioning-with-rails-4

Comment: Thank you so much. I have done the rails for zombies course already :) will definitely look into these other resources.

Comment: If seperate FE and BE then do I need to host two apps seperately or is there any way to host in a common place.

Comment: Hello, you can do it in one app, write your rails background api and add your favorite js framework in assets/javascript to write the front. For the mobile app, make API call to your app :-)